# Enable to show paste UI in my keypad for EditText which is customize

Tags: android, clipboard, copy-paste

I am working on Application where it required Keypad where i have prevent soft-keyboard for EditText by Below Custom EditText Code but using this code i can able to achieve disable soft-keyboard from being open.But this make paste functionality to be not working.

https://code.google.com/p/ics-custom-contacts/source/browse/src/com/android/contacts/dialpad/DigitsEditText.java

Above this code which i have use to suppresses IME show up work fine but paste is not working as normally.

Here is reference screen shot for default app of keypad which work fine for paste .

So i want my keypad EditText to work like this default keypad app.Do any one have idea to make it work paste functionality.

[image]